# How do I CLICK the 'delete' button in the popup from MESSAGES in MacOS Big Sur using AppleScript?

Tags: popup, click, applescript, message, macos-big-sur

What is the simple way to get the 'delete' button 'clicked' in response to the popup pictured below from the Messages app?  I've tried more variations than I care to admit and am feeling humbled.

This code works fine if I want to 'click' the 'cancel' button in the popup.

But nothing I have tried has worked to click the 'delete' button.

[Messages popup after delete message pulldown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBcXs.png)

```
tell application "Messages"
    activate
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    key code 2 using command down
end tell


tell application "System Events"
    set frontmost to true
    delay 1
    click button "Cancel"
end tell
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you.

```
tell application "System Events" to tell application process "Messages"
    set frontmost to true
    repeat until frontmost
        delay 0.1
    end repeat
    click UI element "Delete" of sheet 1 of window 1
end tell
```